# zoom issue in dagre-d3 when use with vuejs2 with watch mode

Tags: d3.js, vue.js, vuejs2, dagre-d3, dagre

I am using d3-dagre to render the data. Initially i can render the data without any problem. When i try to update the same view in watch mode, it is updating the data but still some error is thrown in the console for "g" attribute transformation. Whenever i try to rewrite the SVG elements i am removing the "g" element inside the "svg" tag. I am trying this in vuejs2 ui library.

```
 watch: {
  workflowDetails: function (changes) {
  console.log('Update component ==> ' + changes)
  this.workflowName = changes.label
  this.workflowDetails = changes
  this.metricGraph = false
  this.drawDAGView()
  }
},
mounted () {
  this.drawDAGView()
},
methods: {
getJobid: function (nodeId) {
  console.log('Function to get graph api' + nodeId)
  this.metricGraph = true
},
drawDAGView: function (isUpdate) {
   /* eslint-disable */
```

> ```
>    d3.selectAll('svg > g').remove()
> ```

```
    // Create a new directed graph
    var g = new dagreD3.graphlib.Graph().setGraph({})

    var DagNodes = this.workflowDetails.nodes
    var fillColor
    // Add states to the graph, set labels, and style
    Object.keys(DagNodes).forEach(function(key) {
        console.log("Nodes - "+ DagNodes[key].name)
        var value = DagNodes[key]
        value.label = DagNodes[key].name + " (" + DagNodes[key].exec_time + ")"
        value.rx = value.ry = 5
        g.setNode(DagNodes[key].name, value)
    })

    var DagEdges = this.workflowDetails.edges;
    // Add states to the graph, set labels, and style
    Object.keys(DagEdges).forEach(function(key) {
        g.setEdge(DagEdges[key].startEdge,  DagEdges[key].endEdge, { label: ""} )
    })

    // Create the renderer    
    var render = new dagreD3.render()

    // Set up an SVG group so that we can translate the final graph.
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    inner = svg.append("g")

    // Set up zoom support
    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function() {
        inner.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" +
                                    "scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
    })
    svg.call(zoom)

    // Simple function to style the tooltip for the given node.
    var styleTooltip = function(name, description) {
    return "<p class='name'>" + name + "</p><p class='description'>" + description + "</p>"
    }

    // Run the renderer. This is what draws the final graph.
    render(inner, g)

    inner.selectAll("g.node")
    .attr("title", function(v) { 
        return styleTooltip(v, "Execution Time: "+g.node(v).label + " <br /> Description: "+g.node(v).label) 
    })
    //.each(function(v) { $(this).tipsy({ gravity: "w", opacity: 1, html: true }) })
    var self = this
    inner.selectAll("g.node")
    .on("click", function(v) {
        console.log("Nodes --> "+ v + " -- "+ g.node(v).node_id)
        // whatever
        //window.location = "../dag/"+g.node(v).job_id
        self.nodeId = g.node(v).node_id
        console.log("Node id -- "+ self.nodeId)
        self.getJobid(self.nodeId)
    })

    // Center the graph
    var initialScale = 1.2
    zoom
    .translate([(svg.attr("width") - g.graph().width * initialScale) / 50, 20])
    .scale(initialScale)
    .event(svg)
    svg.attr('height', g.graph().height * initialScale + 40)
    svg.attr('width', "100%")
}
```

Error - Due to this below error newly loaded data not able to zoom

```
Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(NaN,20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the svg? After removing the svg you can add the new Graph.